# unable to create java package in maven project imported in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-3

I've imported a maven project into Intellij and added a module to the `src` directory. But now I discovered that I cannot add a java package to new directory as I can with other projects, i.e., whenever I right click on the newly added directory, Intellij does not give me the possibility to add a java package. It would seem that this is a setting issue but I cannot find the setting that would control this. I'm using the community edition of Intellij: 2018.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is your `src` folder not marked as sources folder . Try below step

1. From the main menu, select File | **Project Structure(Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S)** and click Project `Settings | Modules`.
2. Select the `src` folder mark with sources folder.

Now you can able to create the Packages under `src`